# How to get total duration for all object in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I am using MongoDB 3.4.18. I have the following collection name : `student_details` . The data inside it looks like this :

```
{
_id : ObjectID(generated_id),
in_time : <student_registered_in_time>
student_id : 'abc',
out_time: <student_registered_out_time>,
date_r: <date_in_ISO_FORMAT>
} , 
{
 _id : ObjectID(generated_id),
 in_time : <student_registered_in_time>
 student_id : 'def',
 out_time: <student_registered_out_time>,
 date_r: <date_in_ISO_FORMAT>
}
```

I want to print the total amount of time spend by student having a particular `student_id` (let's say `abc` ) for particular day. For e.g the output should be

```
{
'student_id' : 'abc', 
'total_time_spent': 'total_time_spent_in_minutes'
'date': date
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried the following though.

```
  db.student_details.aggregate([
        { 
        $match: {
          date_r: {
            $gte: ISODate("2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2018-11-31T23:59:59.000Z")
          } , 
          student_id : 'abc',    
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          total: {
            $sum: <confused_about_this_part>
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Comment: will there be multiple in/outs for particular day?

Comment: @PrabhatMishra yes. For the same student_id there can be multiple in and outs.

Comment: Could you post the actual sample data from your mongo database